# What's a recommended way to build a HTML5 mobile app?

Tags: performance, html, mobile, sencha-touch

Although we are new to this technology, we are working on a HTML5 mobile app nowadays with sencha-touch and some other js libs like i18n.

The problems are that:

1. No matter how much we try to tune the performance, it feels kinda slow.
2. Every time we change to another page, when the browsers are loading the next page, there is a ugly blank-paged interval.

We think we might miss some structural and best practices here with HTML5 mobile app. We speculate that we are still treating HTML5 mobile app with our web logic.

That's why I would like to ask:

1. Is it okay to add in some other js except for sencha-touch? Is it the thing that drags the speed here?
2. Is a multi-paged mobile app a good practice? Or should we build everything within the same html page?
3. Is there a way to pre-load everything so that the page change can be faster?

Thanks

Comment: It will always feel slow/clunky no matter what framework you try. You should abandon HTML5 and go native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha touch has good performance, also they promise even greater performance in the upcoming (around October 26th) sencha touch 2 (http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-what-to-expect). So the sencha touch as a JS library is well optimized. Maybe you are app is not well optimized or something else is slowing it down. All in all, my point is that sencha touch as a JS library is arguably as good as JS library could get, so it isn't the problem at all.

All JS applications should be one page HTML. There are ways how to maintain the browser history and state, if that's your concern.

There are couple of ways to pre-load and cache everything, but if you do the one page HTML web app then you don't really have to.

So my advice is to stick with sencha touch, at least until the sencha touch 2 comes out, and see if the performance issues are solved, before moving to other solutions. Also first thing you need to do is to make it a single HTML page app and do some testing and measuring to see what is slowing the app down.

Comment: Thanks Ilya139. How do you usually conduct the performance test to see what is slowing your apps down?

Comment: Also, do you have any recommended reading about the file structure of a mobile app?

Comment: To test the performance of your app you can use tools like jsperf.com and www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/, or simply output the time needed to execute some function to console (`console.log(time);test();console.log(new Date()-time);`). Also chromes developer tools' timeline is handy to see how much time does the rendering takes, memory e.t.c. All in all there are bunch of tools, but most importantly is to understand your code and to see what looks slow from a user's perspective.

Comment: For the structure of a mobile app I recommend the MVC pattern. See tutorials about it and sencha touch here:  http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap and here http://vimeo.com/28219285

Answer (score 1):

I personally use JQuery Mobile.

http://jquerymobile.com/

The framework does take some time to understand.  It's full version should be released this month or early next month.  I have been working with it since Alpha.  If you are familiar with JQuery I highly recommend it.  They are taking care of some of the really simple things such as the varying differences between every phone.

Here is a support platform list:
http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

It is ajax driven, but this feature can be turned off.  It can be a little heavy, but considering the amount of work it does to take care of so many odds things on every phone, it really is worth learning it in my opinion.  I would recommend going through the docs & demos to see if this is what you are looking for.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/

If you have any specific questions about it, feel free to ask.